# speed up GIN index creation

Tags: postgresql, indexing

I'm trying to create a GIN index on an hstore column, avg 3KB per row and 2.5M rows. It takes ages (I gave up after 40 minutes). Gist comes back in couple of minutes. Any way to speed this up (or any idea how long it should take...)? I tried increasing maintenance_work_mem but if I push it over 1GB postgres refuses to start, complaining there are errors in postgresql.conf. 
Environment: windows 7 64bits, 8GB RAM, Intel Core i5 and an SSD drive. 
Any help/suggestion appreciated!

Update: tried change the parameter before the index creation. That's what I got...

ERROR:  2097152 is outside the valid range for parameter "maintenance_work_mem" (1024 .. 2097151)
********** Error **********

ERROR: 2097152 is outside the valid range for parameter "maintenance_work_mem" (1024 .. 2097151)
SQL state: 22023

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Increasing maintenance_work_mem is a key to good gin index creation speeds.  I can certainly  increase it to more than 1GB, so you must be doing something wrong, but without seeing the exact error message or the line from the conf file, it is hard to say what that might be.

But it is a bad practise to increase the setting in the config file just to create an index, you should instead increase it in the session which is doing the creation, using something like:

```
set maintenance_work_mem TO "5GB";
```

Comment: Tried that, does not seem to be working however I got an error message (posted in the question). Tx!

Comment: Ah, that's right, you are using Windows.  Well, set it to 2097151 (with no units) then.

Comment: Is this a limitation of postgres on windows? I thought I installed the 64 bits version of postgres on a 64 bits windows... However just checked the postgres process, it's not even using 1GB so I'm possibly barking the wrong tree.

Comment: Yes, Windows made some typing decisions that make it hard to implement larger memory usage in a cross-platform way.  The PostgreSQL developers could work around it, but no one has yet been motivated to do all the work and testing it would take.

Comment: Unbelievable. They should be mentioning this cruel limitations in the docs. I used to wait for index creation for WEEKS on Windows using only 2Gb for maintenance_work_mem while having a server with 128Gb. Especially "nice" feelings I have experienced when the server had a power outage, and 8 day's work of index creation (of course, single-threaded, while again,  server had 32 cores) was lost.